# importing css/sass files in webpack using aliases

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

Is there any way to import `.scss` / `.css` files using aliases

```
// webpack.config.js

resolve: {
  alias: {
    styles: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/styles/"),
  }   
}
```

and in main.js

```
// main.js

import "styles/main.scss";
```

Comment: Does your current example not work?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack alias' should be prefoxed with tilde in sass imports. So your syntax should be:

```
import "~styles/main.scss";
```